# I want to get value of first column row on eack href click in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to get the first column row value on each row href click EDIT . for eg if i click on first row href then i should get alert with its first column row value .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var jsonData = [{
            id: 'A01',
            name: 'Fadhly'
        }, {
            id: 'A02',
            name: 'Permata'
        }, {
            id: 'A03',
            name: 'Haura'
        }, {
            id: 'A04',
            name: 'Aira'
        }];

        $.each(jsonData, function (key, val) {
            var tr = '<tr>';
            tr += '<td>' + (key + 1) + '</td>';
            tr += '<td>' + val.id + '</td>';
            tr += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
            tr += '<td><a href="#menu1">Edit</a</td>';
            tr += '</tr>';
            $('tbody').append(tr);
        });
```

My HTML Code

```
<script           src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>#</th>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In above table if i click on first row edit href then it should print id in alert box. i dont want on button click only href click .

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://www.json.org/) -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: PLease check my updated code and please help to get value on each row href click .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out.

this works perfectly

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var jsonData = [{
            id: 'A01',
            name: 'Fadhly'
        }, {
            id: 'A02',
            name: 'Permata'
        }, {
            id: 'A03',
            name: 'Haura'
        }, {
            id: 'A04',
            name: 'Aira'
        }];

        $.each(jsonData, function (key, val) {
            var tr = '<tr>';
            tr += '<td>' + (key + 1) + '</td>';
            tr += '<td>' + val.id + '</td>';
            tr += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
            tr += '<td><button class="delete" data-key="' + (key + 1) + '"><a href="#menu1">Edit</a></button></td>';
            tr += '</tr>';
            $('tbody').append(tr);
        });

         $('tbody .delete a').click(function(){
             alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child').text());
         });
});
```

here is the updated jsfiddle link. check it out.
https://jsfiddle.net/86n7qkpe/

Comment: added jsfiddle link, check that out.

Comment: I removed first column from hmtl table and then i should get id but still it is giving me 1 as output . but it should give me the value of first column row

Comment: Thnx for the explaination and for answer also . Both you and Alexander gave right answer i m confused to whose answer i should accept and tick right

Comment: I understand that, but thank you very much for accepting mine :)

Comment: How can i add pagination to above html table .

Answer (score 1):

Given a generated HTML structure as follows with **n** rows being **dynamically added** to `<tbody>`:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>
        <a>Edit</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><!-- n dynamically generated rows --></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You could use the following jQuery to execute `alert()` of the text within the first column of the respective row using click handler with a context provided:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tbody').on('click', 'a', function(){
        var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').first().text();
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0egbfruz/4/) demonstrating the functionality. It demonstrates the value of the first column being alerted as well as shows dynamic/added rows via click event executing the event on `<a>` click. This is because the `<a>` elements aren't directly targeted, they are supplied as context to permanent DOM element such as  which won't be added or removed.

**Update**

If you need to grab other columns you could structure the jQuery query using `eq()` to grab a zero (0) based index. For example if you need the second column you could:

```
// first column
var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();

// second column
var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text();

// third column
var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(2).text();
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I am creating dynamic table on page load so this code will not work i guess .

Comment: How the `on('click')` handler is set up allows for dynamic elements to be added and have the event listener attached. If `<a>` was being targeted for the 'on()', it would fail, but targeting `<tbody>` (or a similar permanent DOM element) and provided `<a>` context, it will successfully attach as you add more items. I've updated the jsfiddle showing a new row being added and the event successfully executing. Thanks!

Comment: I dont want to add row but i m fetching json from servlet and the on page load  i am creating a html table dynamically using above code and now i want the first column row value on the row edit is clicked . how can i get that value on each efit href click please help..

Comment: The adding of the row in the jsfiddle is simply showing that event handlers can be attached to elements dynamically added to the table. My point wasn't that you **need** to add rows to the table via a button click, it's fine you are adding them looping through JSON. The fiddle demonstrates that even for dynamically added rows, you can use that jQuery to click on an `<a>` and alert the text within the first `<td>` of that respective `<tr>`. If this isn't what you are looking for, you may need to clarify question with examples of what the rows come out to and what **exact value** you need alert

Comment: In the example, the first column is a `<td>1</td>` of the first `<tr>`. When you click on that `<tr>`'s `<a>`, it alerts `1`. If the text within that first `<td>` was instead `<td>foo</td>`, it would alert `foo`.

Comment: Thnx for the explaination and for answer also . Both you and yunus gave right answer i m confused to whose answer i should accept and tick right

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Choose whichever answer seems easier for you maintain and understand. I personally do everything possible to avoid string concatenation unless absolutely necessary for building event functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.each(jsonData, function (key, val) {
        var tr = '<tr>';
        tr += '<td>' + (key + 1) + '</td>';
        tr += '<td>' + val.id + '</td>';
        tr += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
        tr += '<td><button class="delete" data-key="' + (key + 1) + '" onclick="alert('+(key+1)+')"><a href="#menu1">Edit</a></button></td>';
        tr += '</tr>';
        $('tbody').append(tr);
    });
```

Simply add it to the onclick attribute...

Comment: i dont on button click i mentioned above